# How to display same value in different timeframes with pine script?

Tags: pine-script

This is a snippet from the code:

```
Length = (20)
dhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", high) 
dlow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", low)
ADR = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", 100 * (ta.sma(dhigh/dlow, Length) - 1))
```

I later display ADR value in the table. It should be a constant value on all timeframes, but it is not - it is the same on all below daily timeframes, but not weekly, for example.

How do I make it constant across ALL timeframes?
Please, help.

I read manual and could't find answer to that.
I also googled for similar issues online, but could not find ideas to try out.

Answer (score 0):

The [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe) function was designed to request data of a timeframe higher than the current chart timeframe.

If you want to get data from lower timeframes, you should use [request.security_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?highlight=request#request-security-lower-tf) function.

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("`request.security_lower_tf()` Example")
float travel = math.abs(high - low)
float[] ltfTravelArray = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1", travel)
float volatility = nz(array.sum(ltfTravelArray) / travel)
plot(volatility)
```

Comment: That's a helpful hint. Thank you!